# Lock a window to the foreground without focus

Tags: windows-7, macos, monitoring

Often times I find that there's a lot of useless space on a window I have open that I wish I could use for monitoring something else (for example, watching the progress of a script in terminal).
Is there any way I can lock a window to the foreground without it necessarily having focus? 
As an example, if I have two windows, A and B, and I want to watch B while editing A, I want to:

- Be able to move and resize B
- Have B cover A
- Enter text and click in A, without A covering B
- Be able to toggle whether B is locked to the foreground or not.

Is there any way I can do this? I'm currently using mountain lion but if there's a solution in windows 7 that'd be helpful as well.

Comment: The functionality you're looking for is commonly called "Always on Top" in Windows. There are several tools available to make this possible. Here is a quick find: http://www.labnol.org/software/tutorials/keep-window-always-on-top/5213/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Windows someone wrote an [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script that will do it.

- [Download Always on Top - Keep Any Window Visible Always](http://www.labnol.org/software/tutorials/keep-window-always-on-top/5213/)

Another Windows option (also created with AutoHotKey) is [DesktopCoral](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Mouser/desktopcoral/) which lets you block off a section of your screen so that maximized windows won't cover it.

For OS-X I saw [Afloat](http://infinite-labs.net/afloat/) mentioned several times but some folks seemed to have issues with it.